# “Based on” X, we can say Y?

Tags: past-participles, subordinate-clauses, participial-phrases, absolute-constructions, subordinators

> **Based on** the evidence available, I’m not sure I can conclude anything.

We often say that X is based on Y to mean X is grounded in, or adapted from, Y. But can we use it as above as if it were a sort of absolute construction meaning “because or in light of”? I’ve seen a few such examples but have only just wondered if they were correct.

Comment: Basically this sentence is saying that the speaker has insufficient evidence to come to a conclusion. For instance he could be looking at a farm with an 18th century house which suggests that the land has been farmed for at least that long but the only other buildings he can see are modern dairy facilites. He would be unable to come to the conclusion that the farm had never been used for raising sheep, however, becasue there is no evidence that that did or did not happen there in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Logic is introduced with syllogisms such as "Whenever A then B. Now we have A and so we can expect B" The same could apply if A means we will *never* have C.

Your statement says that they can conclude nothing based on the current circumstances. They fail to describe what requirements they have for some conclusion. The sentence is meaningful and not spurious but it walks away from logic and throws up its hands.